# How do I write a visual JavaBean?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I am developing a `JavaBean` which `extends Canvas`. It is very simple and I use it in jsp file using `<jsp:plugin>` tag. **I use google chrome to connect to page I receive**. 
`InvocationTargetException` here is the code

```
package exsys.nurse_desktop;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class NurseDesktopControl extends Canvas implements Serializable {

    public NurseDesktopControl() {
        setSize(100, 100);
        setBackground(Color.blue);

        System.out.println("constructor");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("painting");     
    }   
}
```

I need detailed step by step how to write basic visual JavaBean, including how to compile it and then how to use it in jsp with .

Comment: post the error and the jsp

Comment: <%--
 Copyright 2004-2005 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
 Use is subject to license terms.
--%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<html>
 <head><title>Hello</title></head>
 <body bgcolor="white">
  <jsp:plugin type="bean" code="exsys.nurse_desktop.NurseDesktopControl.class">
  </jsp:plugin>

 </body>
</html>